# Java annotations: at variable initialization, but not assignment?

Tags: java, syntax, annotations

I've been having trouble understanding where exactly an annotation has to or can be placed.

The class with this method compiles, but gives a warning "unchecked":

```
<B extends BitSet> void doStuff(LinkedList<B> list) {
    B board = list.getFirst();
    B cloneBoard;
    cloneBoard = (B) board.clone(); //unchecked
}
```

This compiles without warning:

```
<B extends BitSet> void doStuff(LinkedList<B> list) {
    B board = list.getFirst();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    B cloneBoard = (B) board.clone();
}
```

This doesn't compile but marks cloneBoard with an error:

```
<B extends BitSet> void doStuff(LinkedList<B> list) {
    B board = list.getFirst();
    B cloneBoard;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    cloneBoard = (B) board.clone(); // cloneBoard cannot be resolved to a type;
                                    // VariableDeclaratorID expected
}
```

In the Sun tutorial on annotations, I couldn't find an answer as to why this is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html.

The grammar definition didn't help me either, since I'm not quite sure I understand it correctly: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html#18.1

It seems to me that what's the problem here is that annotations can be specifically used for variables, but only when they are declared; any later assignment will not be covered by the annotation. Is this correct? Is there a more elegant solution than suppressing unchecked warnings for the whole method?

Comment: Woah, your answers came way faster than I expected, thanks! All of them were really helpful; I accepted ruakh's answer for the useful part one elegance (especially the code part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An annotation is part of a declaration; just as you can't write `Object obj` except at the point where `obj` is declared, nor `final obj` except as `final Object obj`, so too is `@Deprecated obj` forbidden.

As for elegance — ideally your methods should not be very long and complicated, anyway, but if you do find that you'd like to mark a specific assignment with this annotation, you can always make use of a simple wrapper method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends ClassThatDeclaresCloneAsPublic> T cloneObj(T obj)
    { return (T) obj.clone(); }
```

(Though in this specific case, I suppose you could write `cloneBoard = board.getClass().cast(board.clone());` and dispense with the annotation altogether, if you wanted.)

Comment: If you're wondering why you got +15 again today, I was curious whether it really is possible to "un-accept" an answer after such a long time :P

Answer (score 3):

From [Java Language Specification - Interfaces > Annotation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7)

> Annotations may be used as modifiers in any declaration, whether package, class, interface, field, method, parameter, constructor, or local variable..

It can only use in a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are part of the declaration (others have already answered this part).

However, to answer the second part of your question:
I have never had a problem marking the whole method with this annotation when the method is short like this. I personally prefer annotations on the method/class level rather than inside of methods because I think they just distract the reader.